# How to remove this error in FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to show the data submitted in html form in pdf.
I've gone through all the solutions given on previous questions but I'm unable to solve this. 
I'm getting the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: s_
>   name in C:\xampp\htdocs\dynamic website\form1.php on line 9
>   FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Part of my html code is

```
<td align="right" valign="top">
  <label for="student3_name">3.Name </label>
  </td>
<td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="student3_name" maxlength="50" size="20" >
  </td>
```

and my form1.php is as follows:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {$s_name = $_POST["student3_name"];}
   require ("fpdf/fpdf.php");
   $pdf=new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
   $pdf->Cell(0,50,'',0,1);
   $pdf->Cell(60,10,"hello{$s_name}",10,8,'C');
   $pdf->output();
?>
```

EDIT:
here is the detailed part my form

```
<form name="submission_form" method="post" action="form1.php">
  <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 900;></p>
  <table width="634" align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top">
  <label for="student3_name">3.Name </label>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="student3_name" maxlength="50" size="20" >
  </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @Daan I've checked this question already but I'm unable to solve this by using answer given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<?php
       $s_name = "";
       if(isset($_POST['submission_form']))
       {
               $s_name = $_POST["student3_name"];
       }
       require ("fpdf/fpdf.php");
       $pdf=new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
       $pdf->AddPage();
       $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
       $pdf->Cell(0,50,'',0,1);
       $pdf->Cell(60,10,"hello{$s_name}",10,8,'C');
       $pdf->output();
    ?>
```

Change your submit button to this

```
<input name="submission_form" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

You are declaring $s_name variable inside a block, that variable is invisible outside of the block so you cannot use it anywhere else except inside the block where it is declared.

Comment: Thank you now error is removed but in my pdf file I cannot see the value of s_name.I'm entering the student3_name but it is not displayed.

Comment: Whats your form Method?? is that `GET` OR `POST`?

Comment: this condition isset($_POST['submit']) is returning false thats why. can you show me the form that you are submitting?

Comment: @CoDeMurDeRer it is 'POST'.

Comment: show me the html form code that you re submitting. you are never post the value 'submit' $_POST['submit'] from your html form

Comment: @Arlind I've added the code in the question in EDIT section.
I've copied this part out of my code.

Comment: I edited my answer change 
$_POST['submit']  to $_POST['submission_form']

Comment: I've tried this but same problem. I just added the else condition and it is confirming that my form isn't submitted yet.
so what should I change to get the required solution!

Comment: I edited my answer it works on my server. I changed the html code for your input submit button

Answer (score 0):

You need an else condition that will define `s_name` in the case that `isset($_POST['submit'])` returns false.

Something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $s_name = $_POST['student3_name'];
} else {
    $s_name = 'The form hasn\'t been submitted yet!';
}
```

Keeping up with your edits:

Also ensure that the submit button is posting its value. In order for this to occur you need to include a name attribute:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: I've added this and it is confirmed that my form isn't submitted so how to solve this problem.

Comment: In that case, this is the answer you've asked for. Perhaps if the form is not submitted you will want to avoid outputting a pdf entirely. In this case you can wrap the entire pdf generating code in the 1st block of the if statement.
You'll need to post a new question that's more specific to the problem you're now having, because this question only deals with how $s_name was not being properly initialized.